# Svelte/Sapper - Encountered a build related bug with Luxon & Lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash, svelte, sapper, luxon

So I've just rolled out a new page (`dashboard.svelte`) on my prototype booking management app - I committed it along with a bunch of other changes and deployed to my Bitnami Node.js (Ubuntu 16.04) VPS.

Builds fine, but when loading any of the site in the browser, I get a bizarre error in the console which breaks execution of all other JS.

`TypeError: Kn is not a function` which ties back to the `return Kn(t...` section of a file called `map.xxx.js`:

```js
var Kn, Xn = function (t, e) {
  return function (n, r) {
    if (null == n) return n;
    if (!qe(n)) return t(n, r);
    for (var i = n.length, o = e ? i : - 1, a = Object(n); (e ? o-- : ++o < i) && !1 !== r(a[o], o, a); );
    return n
  }
}(function (t, e) {
  return t && Qn(t, e, Pe)
}); var tr = function (t, e) {
  var n = - 1,
  r = qe(t) ? Array(t.length)  : [
  ];
  return Kn(t, function (t, i, o) {
    r[++n] = e(t, i, o)
  }),
  r
};
```

I spent several hours trying to track down the source of this bug (which to be honest is not very intuitive), and through trial and error tied it back to the aforementioned `dashboard.svelte` file (which works fine in `npm run dev` by the way)

https://gist.github.com/Bandit/58500ebc473e7d8d84bfb6ae16d41ea6

I've put all the information I can find about this in the above gist. I really hope someone can shed some light on the issue because I've had to rollback to an earlier commit for now.

FWIW I use `DateTime` via Luxon and several `lodash` methods elsewhere in the application without any issues, so it's not like this is the first time these packages have been built.

/EDIT1 Should note that if I `rm src/routes/dashboard.svelte` then `npm run build` everything works fine, so it's completely constrained to that one file...

/EDIT2 Commenting out the following lines in `dashboard.svelte` makes everything work fine:

```js
    // import merge from 'lodash/merge';

    // const { session } = stores();
    // $session.prefs = merge({}, $session.prefs);
```

But this makes no sense to me because this EXACT code exists in another page within my app:

```js
    import merge from 'lodash/merge';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { hideAll } from 'tippy.js';
    import { numberWithOrdinal } from './_helpers.js';
    import { hasRole } from 'user.js';

    const { session } = stores();
    $session.prefs = merge({}, $session.prefs);
```

So it's something to do with the order of the imports?

/EDIT3 Regarding my comment below with the callstack, this is the line that triggers the issue (which is in a totally different file to `dashboard.svelte` and runs fine on the server):

```js
    $: if (dates && availableItems && availableBookings) populateGrid();
```

/EDIT4 So after extensive debugging we managed to pin it down to `lodash.sortBy`. Not sure why that is suddenly an issue as I've been using it for weeks without problem on another page within the app. Anyway I've removed all traces of it for now and all is well. For now (because I don't believe that is truly the issue)...

Answer (score 2):

It's harder to debug because the JavaScript has been uglified.

In your `rollup.config.js` disable the `terser` plugin. (You can just comment it out)

Then re-run your build and it should give you non-mangled naming.

Another debugging tip is to edit the JS file `map.xyz.js` and add a `debugger` statement right before the line causing the error. Then re-run with devtools open. It will stop at that line and display the call stack. Look thru the call stack, it may shed light on where it's coming from.

Comment: I disabled `terser` and re-ran the build but it made no difference? I put a breakpoint using Firefox dev tools at the point - this is the call stack: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u3idxu6g9dicq9i/Screenshot%202019-12-10%2020.45.23.png?dl=0

Comment: Commenting out the `lodash/merge` import fixes the issue - but why? I use it elsewhere in the app just fine. Added more info to original question

Comment: The top of the callstack is `update` in `bookings.js`, click into that, it should show what line started the trouble.

Comment: In your code, why do you set `$session.prefs` with an assignment? Shouldn't you always be updating a store by calling `myStore.update()` function? Maybe related?

Comment: I use that same code elsewhere - but to my knowledge the `session` store is treated differently? I used this as reference (as [session isn't yet documented...](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Stores)): https://github.com/sveltejs/realworld/blob/master/src/routes/login/index.svelte

Comment: Usually a store is updated by calling `update()`, ie `session.update(oldValue => ...)`.
Also, when you do `$session.prefs = merge({}, $session.prefs)`, what is the reason for doing that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203963/discussion-between-james-nisbet-and-joshnuss).